# Optimize the display value in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please let me know how I can optimize more below code in one line:

```
 {addressToDisplay?.addressLineOne}
      {addressToDisplay?.addressLineTwo}
      {addressToDisplay?.city}
      {addressToDisplay?.state}
      {addressToDisplay?.zip}
```

Comment: only for those attributes? or all of values in `addressToDisplay`? let me know what addressToDisplay has and how it looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
Object.keys(addressToDisplay).map(function(key) {
   return <>{ addressToDisplay[key] }</>
})
```

And to display both key, value you can add:

```
Object.entries(addressToDisplay).map(([key, val]) => 
                    <h2 key={key}>{key}: {val}</h2>
                )
```

If you need specific values then you can store the keys which you need in one array

```
addressField = ['city', 'state', 'lineone', 'linetwo']
```

and then get them by

```
{addressToDisplay && addressField.map(key => <>{addressToDisplay[key]}</>)}
```

Comment: I need to display four value like city,state,lineone and line two.How i can show here.If we use key and value it will display all the values in addressTodisplay

Comment: @user2110253 updated answer according to the above comment.

Comment: giving error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addressLineOne')

Comment: You can change last line to {addressToDisplay && addressField.map(key => <>{addressToDisplay[key]}</>)}

Answer (score 1):

if your object is already well organized you can do this

```
return <>{[...Object.values(addressToDisplay || {})].join` `}</>;
```

Or else you have this kind of solution

```
const {addressLineOne, addressLineTwo, city, state, zip} = addressToDisplay || {};
    
return <>{[addressLineOne, addressLineTwo, city, state, zip].join` `}</>
```

Answer (score 0):

{addressToDisplay &&
addressField.map((key) => <>{addressToDisplay[key]}</>)}